# Accessing/modifying members of a QDialog from a different class?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a class that need to access a `QDialog` member, but I can't make it so that the class can see what it needs to. Just to give some background: the ultimate goal is to make a QTextEdit widget fade out and become hidden after 5 seconds of being shown. Here's my code (only the relevant bits; I'm asking more about the scope issue than anything):

**dialog.h**

```
#ifndef DIALOG_H
#define DIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>
#include "mytimer.h"

namespace Ui {
class Dialog;
}

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
  ~Dialog();

private:
  Ui::Dialog* ui;
  myTimer mTimer;

};

#endif // DIALOG_H
```

**dialog.cpp**

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"
#include "q_debugstream.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <QTextEdit>

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
  QDialog(parent),
  ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);
  // this works in this .cpp file but not in mytimer.cpp when trying something similar
  ui->someQTextEdit->setTextInteractionFlags(ui->someQTextEdit->textInteractionFlags() | Qt::TextEditable); 

  myTimer mTimer;

}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
  delete ui;
}
```

**mytimer.h**

```
#ifndef MYTIMER_H
#define MYTIMER_H
#include <QtCore>

class myTimer : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  myTimer();
  QTimer* timer;

public slots:
  void mySlot();
};

#endif // MYTIMER_H
```

**mytimer.cpp**

```
#include "mytimer.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <iostream>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QGraphicsOpacityEffect>
#include <QGraphicsItem>
#include <QPropertyAnimation>
#include <QTime>
#include "ui_dialog.h"
#include "dialog.h"

myTimer::myTimer()
{
  timer = new QTimer(this);
  connect(timer,SIGNAL(timeout()),this,SLOT(mySlot()));

  timer->start(5000);
}

void myTimer::mySlot(){

  QGraphicsOpacityEffect *eff = new QGraphicsOpacityEffect(this);
  ui->someQTextEdit->setGraphicsEffect(eff);
  QPropertyAnimation* a = new QPropertyAnimation(eff,"opacity");
  a->setDuration(350);
  a->setStartValue(1);
  a->setEndValue(0);
  a->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::OutBack);
  a->start(QPropertyAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);    
}
```

The problem is with the `ui->someQTextEdit->setGraphicsEffect(eff);` line. The error I get tells me that `ui` is not declared in this scope. `someQTextEdit` refers to the `QTextEdit` widget I made while creating the dialog in designer. What do I have to do in `mytimer.cpp` to be able to access `someQTextEdit` (which is defined in the dialog's `ui_dialog.h` file that gets generated as a result of using the designer).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your timer is used as local variable located on stack not on the heap. So when `Dialog::Dialog` constructor ends its execution this object is immediately destroyed (basics of C++).

Anyway you don't need custom timer. Use `QProperty` animation.

Comment: I think I see what you're saying. where should I be putting the block that starts with `QGraphicsOpacityEffect`? If I put it in `Dialog::Dialog`, it takes effect right away and the QTextEdit is hidden from the very beginning.

Comment: Disregard my comment above. I'm close to getting it working. I just don't know how to set a delay on the animation before it starts.

Comment: There is a sequence animation which contains other animations (it has addPause method).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I moved the animation block of code to `Dialog::Dialog` and added `QTimer::singleShot(5000, a, SLOT(start()));` in place of `a->start(QPropertyAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);`. It now does what I want it to do. Thanks!

Comment: For reference, this question and answer helped me, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33479629/start-qpropertyanimation-delayed